# How to query a DataSet and iterate through the result?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataSet which contains two tables, Publication and Owner, which are linked on Publication ID.  How do I query the dataset?  What I am trying to do is get all of the owners for a particular publication, and then I want to iterate over the resulting set, concatenate the owner names together and populate a label with the information...

But lets begin with, how do i query the dataset?

I also have a DataRelation, can I query that somehow to get the child rows for the current row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADO.NET supports two fundamental approaches for performing filtering and sorting of datasets:

**The DataTable Select Method** - This method is overloaded to accept arguments to filter and sort data rows returning an array of DataRow objects.

**The DataView object sort, filter and find methods** - This object uses the same filter arguments supported by the Select method, but the DataView exposes structures that can be bound to data-aware controls. See [DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)

Iterating over filtered rows is as easy as:

```
DataTable dt;
...
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select(filter))
{
    // ...
}
```

This article contains several examples: [A Practical Guide to .NET DataTables, DataSets and DataGrids - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/practicalguidedatagrids1.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could look into [LINQ to Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386969.aspx), which allows you to perform queries against DataSets with multiple tables.  You can perform joins between the tables on the appropriate columns amongst other things.